# Получение View (Compose)

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как на android compose получать view?
Например.
Имеется метод **showSettingsMenu(ctx:Context,view:View)**.

Так же имеется кнопка. При вызове метода onClick , передаю туда метод showSettingsMenu , но передать view текущей кнопки как аргумент у меня не получаеться. Каким образом можно это сделать?

```
IconButton(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier.then(Modifier.size(23.dp))
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_settings),
                contentDescription = "",
                tint = White
            )
        }
```

Comment: Уточните что за метод showSettingsMenu и зачем ему view. У вас нет никакого view в Compose соответственно либо null, либо в композе меню реализовывать через DropdownMenu...

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, showSettingsMenu мой метод builder который создает меню использую сторонние библиотеки, в которой чтобы установить расположения выпадения меню нужно указать view. ну вообщем вопрос решен, буду использовать DropdownMenu

Comment: Искать позицию на экране можно через https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/OnGloballyPositionedModifier Но такое себе, да.